# PowerShell DSC Composite Resources

Tags: powershell

I have successfully create DSC Configurations and deployed them onto servers. As a next step, I tried to break apart the parts of the Configuration blocks that are common among servers into reusable sections, or in DSC parlance 'composite resources'. After a lot of researching I am still unable to use the composite resources, they are not listed when running 'Get-DSCResource'.

After looking through the 'Get-DSCResource' function, it seems to require a 'DSCResources' subfolder which the PowerShell.org ebook doesn't state but the PowerShell Blog does. The Get-DSCResources function calls Get-Module with the resource name (SimpleConfig in the example). Both don't account for Get-Module not 'seeing' the sub folders when there isn't a psd1 in the root folder (BaseConfiguration in the example). I adapted these approaches resulting in the example below, but that has not succeeded either.

I've looked at:

- PowerShell [Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2014/02/25/reusing-existing-configuration-scripts-in-powershell-desired-state-configuration.aspx)
- PowerShell.org [EBook](https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/ebooks/tree/master/DSC)
- Steven Murawski's DSC [Series](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/10/14/building-a-desired-state-configuration-configuration-part-2/)
- Steven Murawksi's DSC User Group [Presentation](https://plus.google.com/events/cbujdgrf1n4as5vrsf6o82j9drg)

Example Config:

```
# $env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\BaseConfiguration\BaseConfiguration.psd1
@{
    ModuleVersion = '1.0'
    GUID = '84f449fd-8f26-4bb9-908f-eb675c56b5d8'
    Author = 'James Pogran'
}

# $env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\BaseConfiguration\DSCResoures\SimpleConfig\SimpleConfig.schema.psm1
Configuration SimpleConfig
{
    Log LogThis
    {
        Message = "Foo"
    }
}

# $env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\BaseConfiguration\DSCResoures\SimpleConfig\SimpleConfig.psd1
RootModule = "SimpleConfig.schema.psm1"
```

Comment: I haven't read it myself, but have you seen [the DSC Book](https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/ebooks/tree/master/DSC)? It's still in early draft form, but it does have a section on Composite DSC Resources.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I did read that and listed it in my question. The book's section about composite resources, along with being slightly different than the PowerShell Blog site, also does not work

Comment: As long as I ensure that I can see the configuration in the `Get-Command -CommandType Configuration` list (which is part of the command run by DSC to find it) it works for me. I followed the example in the aforementioned DSC book, but I tried placing the composite configuration in the system-wide module folder (not a good approach, but works fine for testing purposes); at `C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\modules\commonconfig` after which it worked perfectly fine. Let me know if you want me to write an answer with a full guide of the steps I went through to get it working.

Comment: I would appreciate it. I've done what you've described before to no avail

Comment: I have written a very verbose description of the steps I performed to create the composite DSC configuration and verify that it worked. I hope it helps you along the way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update 2014-04-12

The original instructions in this answers work correctly, but it shows an incorrect way of creating composite resources which is the reason why the module needs to be explicitly imported before being able to use the composite configuration in the test configuration.

Composite configurations should be created as ordinary DSC resources in the `DSCResources` subfolder of a container module. This is mentioned in the answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250744/powershell-dsc-composite-resources-with-parameters-not-working/22361994#22361994) and I've also written a blog post on [creating composite DSC configurations which take parameters, which gives detailed instructions on the correct approach](http://robertwesterlund.net/post/2014/03/12/creating-a-composite-dsc-configuration-with-parameters).

I've kept the original answer, only with a strike-through, since I think it is still helpful. Also, given the below information, it should be pretty usuable as well.

The reason that the Import-Module call was needed is that only ordinary DSC resources are able to be loaded automatically. The composite configuration should be created in a subfolder of a container module `MyContainerModule\DSCResources\BaseConfig`. The `psm1` file of the container module can be empty and the composite configuration can be exactly as the original answer states (The `Ìmport-DscResource` command use the `Name` parameter instead of the `ModuleName` parameter though, if you want to keep the BaseConfig name there).

## Detailed steps on creating a composite DSC configuration

Below are the steps I performed when I created and verified a composite configuration called `BaseConfig`. I hope this helps serve as a guide for you.

*For all the following steps, I had the PowerShell ISE running as administrator.*

### Create the folder to hold the module

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'
PS C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules> md BaseConfig

    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                         
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                         
d----        2014-03-04     23:45            BaseConfig                                                                   

PS C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules> cd .\BaseConfig
PS C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BaseConfig>
```

### Create the composite configuration file

Naming for this file must end with ".schema.psm1", since this is hard coded into the PowerShell DSC module, the code for which you can find in the folder `C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration`.

```
PS C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BaseConfig> notepad BaseConfig.schema.psm1
```

Into the BaseConfig.schema.psm1 file, I entered the following configuration:

```
Configuration BaseConfig
{
    File TestFile1
    {
        DestinationPath = "C:\CompositeConfigurationCreatedTextFile1.txt";
        Contents = "File1Content";
    }
    File TestFile2
    {
        DestinationPath = "C:\CompositeConfigurationCreatedTextFile2.txt";
        Contents = "File2Content";
    }
}
```

### Create the module manifest

Creating the module manifest is easy, just let PowerShell do it for you.

```
PS C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BaseConfig> New-ModuleManifest -Path .\BaseConfig.psd1 -RootModule BaseConfig.schema.psm1
```

### Verify that the composite configuration is found by PowerShell

After this step, we should have the composite configuration finished. To verify that it can be found, try running the following command and verify the output:

```
PS C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BaseConfig> Import-Module BaseConfig
PS C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BaseConfig> Get-Command -CommandType Configuration

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName                                             
-----------     ----                                               ----------                                             
Configuration   BaseConfig                                         BaseConfig
```

***Important Note**: I found that if I tried to execute the test configuration (below) without importing the module first, it failed; it wasn't able to recognize BaseConfig. After importing the module, the test configuration worked perfectly fine. However, if I later open a new PowerShell session or run Remove-Module in the current PowerShell session (both ways ensures that the module isn't loaded in the current session) the configuration will work just fine. So it seems, for some reason, that it wouldn't find my newly created composite configuration until I had imported the module at least once.*

### Test the composite configuration

To test the composite configuration, create a configuration which configures the configuration on the node localhost, execute it and verify that the expected changes have been made. I have detailed my exact steps in doing this below.

#### Create the test configuration

To use the composite configuration I first created a configuration definition file with the path c:\temp\testconfiguration.ps1

```
PS C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BaseConfig> md c:\Temp

    Directory: C:\

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                         
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                         
d----        2014-03-04     23:47            Temp                                                                         

PS C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BaseConfig> cd \temp
PS C:\temp> notepad testconfiguration.ps1
```

And I gave it the following content:

```
Configuration TestConfiguration
{
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName BaseConfig

    node localhost 
    {
        BaseConfig Common
        {
            # The created configuration did not have any parameters, thus no properties
        }
    }
}

TestConfiguration
```

#### Create the mof file(s)

Then, to create the mof-files, just execute the ps1-file

```
PS C:\temp> .\testconfiguration.ps1

    Directory: C:\temp\TestConfiguration

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                         
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                         
-a---        2014-03-04     23:49       2266 localhost.mof
```

#### Execute the DSC configuration

After this, I let DSC execute the configuration using the following command:

```
PS C:\temp> Start-DscConfiguration TestConfiguration

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
2      Job2            Configuratio... Running       True            localhost            Start-DscConfiguration...
```

#### Verify that the expected changes have been made

Finally, I verified that the composite configuration has been run by verifying the existence of the two files which is should create.

```
PS C:\temp> ls c:\ -Filter *.txt

    Directory: C:\

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                         
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                         
-a---        2014-03-04     23:51         15 CompositeConfigurationCreatedTextFile1.txt                                   
-a---        2014-03-04     23:51         15 CompositeConfigurationCreatedTextFile2.txt
```

Comment: So, the key here is the 'Import-Module' command before trying to run 'Get-DscResource' or compiling the configuration to mof, and is the piece I was missing. You have my eternal thanks, hours have been wasted on this, I can't find mention of this step anywhere. If you don't mind I'll edit your answer to call this out as a required  'development' step, it isn't necessary once compiled or imported, but is necessary every time you start a new session (as you pointed out).

Comment: @JamesPogran The reason that the `Import-Module` call was needed is that only ordinary DSC resources are able to be loaded automatically. The composite configuration should be created in a subfolder of a container module `MyContainerModule\DSCResources\BaseConfig`. The psm1 file of the container module can be empty and the composite configuration can be exactly as the above answer mentioned (The `Ìmport-DscResource` command must be updated to use the `Name` instead of `ModuleName` parameter though, if you want to keep the BaseConfig name there). I have update my answer above to depict this.

Comment: Awesome clarification. The blog post clarified things perfectly. I used your steps to create a ps function to do the work, and submitted it to the PowerShellOrg github repo for inclusion, credited you for the info