# Import-DSCResource in Composite Resource

Tags: powershell, dsc

I can get a composite resource working at a very basic level (thanks to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157256/powershell-dsc-composite-resources), [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250744/powershell-dsc-composite-resources-with-parameters-not-working), [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2014/02/25/reusing-existing-configuration-scripts-in-powershell-desired-state-configuration.aspx) and [the DSC e-book](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=7F868AA697B937FE&resid=7F868AA697B937FE!156&app=Word)).  The issue I run into is whenever I use a resource that I have to use the `Import-DscResource` cmdlet, the composite resource stops working.

I have read all the information I can find on composite resource, and I cannot figure out why this happens.  Here is an example of the resource I am trying to get to work, module directory structure first:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\TestComposite
    TestComposite.psd1
    DSCResources
        TestResource
            TestResource.schema.psm1
            TestResource.psd1
```

Contents of `TestComposite.psd1`

```
@{
ModuleVersion = '1.0'
GUID = '996a9793-dae7-4c25-8fb5-d3fad094d358'
Author = 'Joseph Alcorn'
CompanyName = 'unknown'
Copyright = '(c) 2014 Joseph Alcorn. All rights reserved.'
Description = 'Composite DSC Resource Test'
FunctionsToExport = '*'
CmdletsToExport = '*'
VariablesToExport = '*'
AliasesToExport = '*'
}
```

Contents of  `TestResource.psd1`

```
@{
RootModule = 'TestResource.schema.psm1'
ModuleVersion = '1.0'
GUID = '38ca17b0-7d69-4ad5-bb75-fe4de22290d
Author = 'Joseph Alcorn'
CompanyName = 'unknown'
Copyright = '(c) 2014 Joseph Alcorn. All rights reserved.'
Description = 'Composite DSC Resource Test'
FunctionsToExport = '*'
CmdletsToExport = '*'
VariablesToExport = '*'
AliasesToExport = '*'
}
```

If I have the contents of `TestResource.schema.psm1` be this, the composite resource is recognized and everything works.

```
Configuration TestResource
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $IPAddress
    )

    File TestFile1
    {
        DestinationPath = "C:\TestFile.txt";
        Contents = $IPAddress
    }
}
```

As soon as I change the configuration to this, it is no longer recognized by `Get-DscResource` and any configuration trying to use it will error out.

```
Configuration TestResource
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $IPAddress
    )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xNetworking

    xIPAddress IPAddress
    {
        IPAddress = $IPAddress
        InterfaceAlias = "Ethernet"
        DefaultGateway = "192.168.0.1"
        SubnetMask = "255.255.0.0"
        AddressFamily = "IPv4"
        Ensure = "Present"
    }
}
```

Now, I have the DSC Resource Kit waves 1-3 installed and available, and I can use them with no problem, in fact I created a configuration using the `xNetworking` resource with no issues. When the `TestResource.schema.psm1` file is set to the above, the system no longer sees it as a valid resource (`Get-DscResource` no longer lists it).

If I remove the `Import-DscResource` line but leave everything else out, it recognizes the resource, but the resource is unusable, as it does not know where to find the xNetworking module.  I tried putting the `Import-DscResource -ModuleName xNetworking` in the configuration `.ps1`, hoping that the import would trickle down, but still no luck.

Did I miss something in documentation stating that a composite resource can't use the `Import-DscResource` cmdlet? I don't much see the point of composite resources if you can't use other custom resources in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I feel silly.  The whole issue was the fact that I was mispelling `xNetworking` as `xNetwroking` in my resource.  Fixed the stupid, and I fixed my problem.