# DSC: adding a custom resource to a composite resource

Tags: dsc

I have a composite resource. My understanding is that a composite resource is a collection of configurations that are treated like a resource. I think of resources as a PowerShell module (but not). The current file structure looks like:

**Composite Resource:**

```
…1 Modules
   └ 2 DefaultConfiguration
       └ 3 {version}
            ├ 4 DSCResources
            │    ├ 5 hApplyGpo
            │    │    ├ 5a hApplyGpo.psd1
            │    │    └ 5b hApplyGpo.schema.psm1
            │    └ 6 hStoragePool
            │         ├ 6a hStoragePool.psd1
            │         └ 6b hStoragePool.schema.psm1
            └ 4a DefaultConfiguration.psd1
```

I have just written a custom DSC resource using xDSCResourceDesigner, that has produced the following file structure:

**Custom Resource:**

```
… 7 Modules
   └ 8 hApplyGpo
       └ 9 1.0.0.0
            ├ 10 DSCResources
            │      └ 11 hApplyGpo
            │        ├ 11a hApplyGpo.psm1
            │        └ 11b hApplyGpo.schema.mof
            └ 10a hApplyGpo.psd1
```

Is it possible to merge the two in that `hApplyGpo` resides inside `DefaultConfiguration` or does `hApplyGpo` have to be a separate resource (module) that is referenced by 5b (`Import-DscResource -ModuleName hApplyGpo`)?

If it's possible, where in the composite resource structure should the files from Custom Resource go? My immediate thought is to merge 11 with 5, but what happens to hApplyGpo.psd1 (5a and 10a).

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The composite resource module has the same structure as the custom script resource module. The only difference is that there is no PSM1 file that defines the Get, Set, and Test-TargetResource functions. You can simply copy folders inside the DSCResources folder from the custom resource module to the DSCResources folder of the composite resource or vice versa.

For an example, check the [cWindowsOS](https://github.com/rchaganti/DSCResources/tree/master/cWindowsOS) module I have on Github. It combines custom resources with composite resources in the same resource module.

Answer (score 0):

@ravikanth, Thank you for your input, however, for me it wasn't the complete solution as my resource has multiple composite resources and multiple resources. The key buried in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157256/powershell-dsc-composite-resources) answer is to use `Import-DscResource -Name {resourcename}` as opposed to `Import-DscResource -ModuleName {modulename}` in the composite resource.

I've done a fair bit since posting this question, creating a new custom resource, containing the composite resources which now looks something like:

```
… Modules
   └ hMyResource
        ├ DSCResources
        │   ├───crApplyGpo
        │   │       crApplyGpo.psd1
        │   │       crApplyGpo.schema.psm1
        │   │
        │   ├───crUpdateDriveLetter
        │   │       crUpdateDriveLetter.psd1
        │   │       crUpdateDriveLetter.schema.psm1
        │   │
        │   ├───ARC_hApplyGpo
        │   │       ARC_hApplyGpo.psm1
        │   │       ARC_hApplyGpo.schema.mof
        │   │
        │   └───ARC_hUpdateDriveLetter
        │           ARC_hUpdateDriveLetter.psm1
        │           ARC_hUpdateDriveLetter.schema.mof
        │
        ├ hMyResource.psd1
        └ hMyResource.psm1
```

Taking `crApplyGpo.schema.psm1` as an example:

```
Configuration crApplyGpo 
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param 
    (
        [ValidateSet("Present","Absent")]
        [String]$Ensure = "Present"
    )

    Import-DscResource -Name hApplyGpo
    #Import-DscResource -ModuleName hMyResource #This doesn't work in a composite resource

    hApplyGpo hApplyGpo
    {
        RegistryValue = 0
        Ensure = $Ensure
    }
}
```

However, in the "top-level" configuration, I use `Import-DscResource -ModuleName hMyResource`

HTH